# Boxplot with data from command

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I'm trying to produce a boxplot with `pgfplots` where the data plotted is produced by some other command. Here a MCVE:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
 \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

 \newcommand{\addBoxplot}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
   \begin{axis}%
    \addplot[boxplot = {average = auto}] table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {#1};%
   \end{axis}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
 }

 \newcommand{\getData}{data\\ 1\\ 3\\}

\begin{document}
 % Try 1
 \addBoxplot{data\\ 1\\ 3\\ }

 % Try 2
 \addBoxplot{\getData}
\end{document}
```

Try 1 demonstrates that the `\addBoxplot` command works as expected. Try 2 is the case I really am interested in. This produces an empty boxplot instead of giving just the same plot as try 1. Here is the output for me:

[image: Output for me]

The problem seems to be that the `\getData` is evaluated too late which causes `\addBoxplot` to produce the plot from invalid / empty data.

How can I implement `\addBoxplot` to work in context of try 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\expandafter` can be your best friend (or your worst nightmare).

In this case, `\addBoxplot` doesn't want to see a macro name, it wants to see actual data, so the macro `\getdata` must be expanded once to so that `\addBoxplot` sees the argument in the form it likes.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
 \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

 \newcommand{\addBoxplot}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
   \begin{axis}%
    \addplot[boxplot = {average = auto}] table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {#1};%
   \end{axis}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
 }

 \newcommand{\getData}{data\\ 1\\ 3\\}

\begin{document}
 % Try 1
 \addBoxplot{data\\ 1\\ 3\\ }

 % Try 2
 \expandafter\addBoxplot\expandafter{\getData}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woohoo! This is the solution. Could you elaborate the mystery? I have tried `\expandafter`-variants before. Why do I need two of those?

Comment: I am also curious, I was trying the same, but I thought `\expandafter` would expand the second token encountered?

Comment: @m8mble Think of it like reading left to right, this is the manner in which TeX digests the input.  When getting to the 1st `\expandafter`,  it momentarily skips `\addBoxplot`, and expands the 2nd instance of `\expandafter`, which says to skip the `{` and expand `\getdata` once.  Having performed that much, it goes back and finds `\addBoxPlot{data\\ 1\\ 3\\}`.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi See my prior comment.  It gets really tricky if you want to expand something twice rather than once.  Then you need groups of 3 `\expandafter`s, as in `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addBoxplot\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getData}`.  Can you see why?  The 1st, 3rd, 4th, 6th instances will expand `\getdata` the 1st time, and then the 2nd,5th instances will expand it the 2nd time.  Three expansions require 7 successive `\expandafter`s using the same logic.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi More specifically to your point, "I thought \expandafter would expand the second token encountered", the second token encountered is the `{`, not the `\getData`.